# Xcode 4.3.2; How can I re-link symbols so 'Jump To Definition' works?

Tags: xcode4.3

I recently trashed my Xcode 4.3.2 and download its replacement from the App Store.
Now I can't access symbols for definitions via 'Jump To Definition' contextual menu.

I get 'Symbol Not Found'; ALL THE TIME!

Is there a way to re-index everything so Xcode 4.3.2 is aware?

Comment: Post by jankoen didnt work in my case. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306539/xcode-code-sense-and-cmdclick-to-symbol-doesnt-work-for-1-of-my-projects

Answer (score 1):

I got some improvements when I forced Spotlight to reindex, though the problem is still there, but now sometimes the 'Jump to definition' works, which is an improvement on never jumping.

how to reindex spotlight:

-From the Apple menu, choose System Preferences.

-Click Spotlight.

-Click the Privacy tab.

-Drag a folder or even an entire volume (your hard drive) to the list.

-Remove the item or volume you just added.

( http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2409?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US )

Comment: And then: Restart xCode, and all the jumping will work again.

Comment: Very interesting!
I eventually trashed the whole project and downloaded a fresh one from my subversion repository.   That apparently did the trick.

However, I'm going to follow your link... worth knowing!
Thanks.