# Use Xcode to Jump to Source Code of StdLib

Tags: c, xcode, macos, ctags

When I ctrl-click a stdlib function such as malloc, I get taken to the definition in the header file. This is the behaviour I expect.

I have the correct Darwin source code for the stdlib as downloaded from [Apple OpenSource](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1074/) - specifically:

```
Libc-763.13
```

These have been unpacked in /usr/src. The source for the malloc routine is here:

```
Libc-763.13/gen/malloc.c : line 948
```

So the question is, how can I teach Xcode to jump to the source when I click on malloc in one of my programs?

In the past I have generated ctags files for use in Vim which has given me this functionality. Is there a way to do something similar with Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command+click navigation to jump to a definition should work for all symbols in all Xcode projects.

If it doesn't, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10306634/233201) describes how you might be able to fix it.