# Cmd + click doesn't work on new project from existing source

Tags: xcode

I'm using xcode 4.6.x and creating a blank project in C and adding existing files to it.

When all files are added, the cmd + click navigation doesn't work, stating a "Symbol not found" error.

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?

Btw, I did try the solution suggested in [Xcode code sense and cmd+click to symbol doesn't work for 1 of my projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306539/xcode-code-sense-and-cmdclick-to-symbol-doesnt-work-for-1-of-my-projects), but it's not effective.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with *Swift* project w/ *CocoaPods*.

Try this:
Click on your scheme -> **Manage Schemes** -> make sure that **Container** for your scheme is set to your **Workspace**

P.S.: fixes no Quick Help issue as well

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Does your blank project have a target defined, and do the added modules belong to it?  I've seen cmd+click not work inside modules that didn't belong to the target.

Comment: My project have a External System target defined, but I do not know about the modules. How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps

1) Open "Organizer"

2) Click "Projects" tab

3) CLick "Your Project" at left column

4) Click "Delete" on Derived Data line

5) Restart Xcode

Comment: @DanielRibeiro Try create a new project in new folder and configure him again. It seems, some bug in project configuration.

Comment: "Restart Xcode" is a necessary step. Removing "Derived Data" is not enough.