# Why my Xcode "Command" + "Left Click" not jump to the target function?

Tags: xcode

I have updated my Xcode to 8.2.1.
I am using "Command" + "Left mouse Click" to jump to the target function, although it not working randomly, What's the root cause?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and I follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41619737/830098) to resolve it:

> 1. File > Workspace Settings (or Project Setting)
> 2. Click over the little grey arrow above Advanced... Button (Derived Data)
> 3. Select my project folder and delete it.

After deleted the folder (Derived Data), cmd+left-click starts to jump to the target function again.